# ¿Como hago este tipo de bucles, que de 1049088?

Tags: c#

tengo un codigo pequeño en el que tomo una captura de pantalla la cual almaceno en un bitmap "Bmp"
para despues obtener la cantidad total de colores por cada pixel en un bucle, El problema esta en el bucle no logro que pase por los 1049088 pixeles, solo logro que pase por una linea, aqui el codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PixelColor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Bitmap bmp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public void TakeScreenShot()
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
        }

        public void SearchPixel()
        {
            //Toma la captura de pantalla y guardala en bmp
            TakeScreenShot();

            //La cantidad de pixeles x e y del bmp

            int PX = bmp.Width; //Pixeles en X
            int PY = bmp.Height; // Pixeles en Y
            List<Color> ColorsByBmp = new List<Color>();



                   //Repasar todos los colores de x
                for(int x=0; x < PX; x++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = bmp.GetPixel(x,0);
        ColorsByBmp.Add(pixelColor);

        for (int y = 0; y < PY; y++)
        {
            Color pixelColorY = bmp.GetPixel(0, y);
            ColorsByBmp.Add(pixelColorY);
        }
    }

            Console.WriteLine(ColorsByBmp.Count);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchPixel();
        }

    }
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con este bucle, Nota el tamaño del Bitmap es: 1366 x 768
Intente restar 1 al ancho ya que es mayor y me acerque al resultado pero de cualquier forma no funciono siguio dando una cantidad diferente a lo deseado

Comment: Saludos. Solo estas recorriendo con `PX`; `PY` no lo estas usando.

Comment: Podrias ser mas especifico por favor no entendi gracias :(

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. `for(int x=0; x < PX; x++)` y (digamos) ¿`for(int y=0; y < PY; y++)`?.

Comment: Si usase PY el resultado daria 768 porque cada vez se recorreria 1,1 - 2,2 - 3,3

Comment: Lo acabe de editar usando las dos variables sin exito, disculpa la confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando el tamaño de la imagen que dice 1366*768, tenemos que deben ser hasta 1'049,088 colores (pixeles); debes (viéndolo como una Ancho y Alto) recorrer las 1366 de ancho y a su vez los 768 de alto; por tanto debe ser:

```
for(int x=0; x < PX; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < PY; y++)
   {
      Color pixelColor = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
      ColorsByBmp.Add(pixelColor);
   }
}
// Entonces puedes imprimir el total y (no se si te lo permita la clase "Color" hacer un DiSTINCT
Console.WriteLine(ColorsByBmp.Count);

ColorsByBmp = ColorsByBmp.Distinct().ToList(); // Requiere System.Linq
```

Espero te sea de utilidad; si no queda verifica las dimensiones de tu imagen **BMP**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono!! es usted un genio